# Is it a good practice to share a seed between two linear congruence generators?

Tags: random

I am currently trying two create two specialized versions of the linear congruence generator (pesudo-random number generator) algorithm in my program (and I set the seed to the result of the algorithm every time I generate a random number). I would think that this would make both random number generators more random, but it seems like altering one linear congruence generator implementation ruins the other whenever I'm able to get one of them to be random. Does sharing the seed actually make the program more random in any way, or do both generators behave like one generator when a seed is shared?

Comment: "...I would think that this would make both random number generators more random..." that kind of thinking usually leads to mistakes. Also, you have neglected to provide *any* details about the LCGs, so the question is not answerable.

Comment: Show code in the form of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's hard to know what you're actually doing from your verbal description, you need to show the specifics.